# File Open Fails When W+ Argument Used

Tags: python

I have...

```
datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../some/place'
session_file = '/user_session.json'

with open(datadir + session_file, 'r') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    print data
```

And this works as expected. I can load the json in my json file and access it.

I want to use the `w+` argument so that if the file does not exist it gets created (albeit blank).

Except when I use `w+` the load fails with the error below and the file is overwritten with a blank one.

```
ValueError('No JSON object could be decoded',)
```

How can I create the file if it's not there, but read it if it is, without failing like this?

Comment: I'm not sure how useful creating an empty file will be for you. `json.load` will raise an exception when it tries to parse the empty file, so maybe you should just catch the `FileNotFoundError` (or `IOError` in Python 2) and do whatever is appropriate then.

Comment: Yeah I think this is what's happening. Perhaps I should write some blank dict as json to initialise the file?

Comment: The thing is, the blank file overwrites the good file, even if there's valid json in it.

Comment: Do you really need to create the file if it doesn't exist? If it's not there to read the data from, why not just set `data` to some appropriate value and not bother with the file at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check if the file exists and react accordingly:

```
import json
import os.path

datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
session_file = 'user_session.json'
path = os.path.join(datadir, '..', 'some', 'place', session_file)

# If the file exists, read the data.
if os.path.exists(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        print data
else:
    with open(path, 'w+') as f:
        # Initialize the session file as you see fit.
        # you can't use json.load(f) here as the file was just created,
        # and so it would not decode into JSON, thus raising the same error
        # you are running into.
```

Note the use of `os.path.join` here; this is a better way to construct file paths rather than concatenating strings. Essentially, using `os.path.join` ensures that the file path will still contain valid slashes regardless of your operating system.

Comment: Nice tip on the path join :)

Comment: Although I still don't get why `'w+'` ends up in a valid file being overwritten in my original example.

Comment: `w` means 'open the file for writing, erasing any existing contents'.  `+` means 'also allow reading'.  If you want to open the file for read/write _and preserve the contents_, use `a+`.

Answer (score 0):

try to test whether the file is there

```
import os.path
import os
datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../some/place'
session_file = '/user_session.json'

path = datadir + session_file
if os.path.exists(path ):
    open(path, 'w+').close()

with open( path , 'r') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    print data
```

Comment: The file is there because it loads with `'r'`. But I like your approach :)

Comment: That won't fix the problem – the read would fail when you call `json.load` with the value of `w+`.

Comment: @RushyPanchal agree, fixed